# Why can't the server machine in travis CI locate my requirements file?

Tags: python, travis-ci

My directory tree looks like this

```
├── antimony_combinations
│   ├── antimony_combinations.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── LICENCE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── tests.py
```

And my `.travis.yml` looks like this:

```
language: python
before_install:    # get some dependency software. This works as expected in another package. 
  - wget https://github.com/copasi/COPASI/releases/download/Build-207/COPASI-4.25.207-Linux-64bit.tar.gz -O /tmp/copasi.tar.gz
  - tar -xzvf /tmp/copasi.tar.gz
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/COPASI-4.25.207-Linux-64bit/bin/
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
  - "3.8"
install:
  - pip install .
  - pip install -r $PWD/requirements.txt     # Also tried just using `requirements.txt` here
  - pip install nose
script:
  - nosetests
after_success:
  - coveralls
```

And yet I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you did not commit your requirements file on GitHub. I would have expected to see it in https://github.com/CiaranWelsh/AntimonyCombinations/tree/58af0a810aed080e6f397d40d009b1b8d45df833!

Comment: Aaahh I've figured it out. I copied a `.gitignore` from another project and forgot to remove the `*.txt`. That was confusing! Thanks for the help.